# SMTP error goes directly to Badmail directory after Queue

Tags: smtp

This is the error I got in the .BDR

> Unable to deliver this message because the follow error was
>   encountered: "This message is a delivery status notification that
>   cannot be delivered.".
>
> The specific error code was 0xC00402C7.
>
> The message sender was <>.
>
> The message was intended for the following recipients.
>     admin@alrconsultores.com

This is the .bad file I got in the badmail error,

Can anyone help me ? I´m getting this error from every mail I try to deliver from several php apps and other apps, the relay is only for 2 ip adresses 127.0.0.1 and the server ip, I telnet the smtp and it seems to work fine the mail go to the queue folder... Im stucked

> From: postmaster@ALRSERVER02 To: admin@alrconsultores.com Date: Mon,
>   22 Aug 2011 18:39:38 -0500 MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type:
>   multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
>     boundary="9B095B5ADSN=_01CC61236DC6DEED00000001ALRSERVER02"
>   X-DSNContext: 7ce717b1 - 1378 - 00000002 - C00402CF Message-ID:
>    Subject: Delivery Status Notification
>   (Failure)
>
> This is a MIME-formatted message.   Portions of this message may be
>   unreadable without a MIME-capable mail program.
>
> --9B095B5ADSN=_01CC61236DC6DEED00000001ALRSERVER02 Content-Type:
>   text/plain; charset=unicode-1-1-utf-7
>
> This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification.
>
> Delivery to the following recipients failed.
>
> ```
>    slopez@alrconsultores.com
> ```
>
> --9B095B5ADSN=_01CC61236DC6DEED00000001ALRSERVER02 Content-Type:
>   message/delivery-status
>
> Reporting-MTA: dns;ALRSERVER02 Received-From-MTA: dns;ALRSERVER02
>   Arrival-Date: Mon, 22 Aug 2011 18:39:38 -0500
>
> Final-Recipient: rfc822;slopez@alrconsultores.com Action: failed
>   Status: 5.3.5
>
> --9B095B5ADSN=_01CC61236DC6DEED00000001ALRSERVER02 Content-Type:
>   message/rfc822
>
> Received: from ALRSERVER02 ([74.3.161.94]) by ALRSERVER02 with
>   Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.0.6002.18264);     Mon, 22 Aug 2011 18:39:38 -0500
>   Subject:
>   =?utf-8?Q?[MantisBT]_Reinicializaci=C3=B3n_de_Contrase=C3=B1a?= To:
>   slopez@alrconsultores.com X-PHP-Originating-Script:
>   0:class.phpmailer.php Date: Mon, 22 Aug 2011 17:39:38 -0600
>   Return-Path: admin@alrconsultores.com From: Alr Tracker
>    Message-ID:
>    X-Priority:
>   3 X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.1 (phpmailer.sourceforge.net) MIME-Version:
>   1.0 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit Content-Type: text/plain;
>   charset="utf-8" X-OriginalArrivalTime: 22 Aug 2011 23:39:38.0020 (UTC)
>   FILETIME=[C182E640:01CC6124]
>
> Si solicitÃ³ este cambio, visite la siguiente URL para cambiar su
>   contraseÃ±a:
>
> Usuario: slopez  DirecciÃ³n IP remota: 189.191.159.86
>
> NO RESPONDA A ESTE MENSAJE
>
> --9B095B5ADSN=_01CC61236DC6DEED00000001ALRSERVER02--

Comment: Windows server 2008

Comment: The secret to SMTP is to check the logs.  If this is the only situation of your mails failing,  then you'll have to look to see if the mails are formatted correctly and if they're failing enmasse or just a portion.  If it's a portion it could be something simple like DNS.  If they're all failing, there could be a few reasons why.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't configure your Exchange server to accept mails for `slopez@alrconsultores.com`. So it tries to inform `admin@alrconsultores.com` about that situation. But unfortunately this user is unknown, too.

So configure your Exchange to accept both mail addresses and the problem is gone.

Comment: is a simple smtp with IIS 6 not exchange  server

Comment: So what? Then replace the word "Exchange" with "IIS 6" and the answer is still valid.

Comment: is an outgoing mail with smtp, in IIS I only got relay access and so... everything seems to be configured... I think it is not necessary to configure valid outgoing email addresses

Comment: According to your DNS entries the server you are talking about is responsible for the given domain. If you don't configure it to accept mails for that domain, you will receive these errors. Either configure your DNS or your SMTP server to handle mail service for `alrconsultores.com`.